# For what $k$ does $\lim_{x \to-\infty} \frac{5^{kx}-1}{5^{-2x} + 1}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

For what values of $k$ does this limit exist?

$$\lim_{x \to-\infty} \frac{5^{kx}-1}{5^{-2x} + 1}$$

*Progress*: I worked it by dividing everything by $5^{-2x}$ and now have $5^{x(k+2)}$ since the bottom half ended up being $1$ and the top ends up $5^{x(k+2)} - 0$. But I just don't know what to make of it from here. Could $k$ be any number except $2$?

Comment: Intuitively or roughly what do you think answer is? The denominator goes to $\infty$, so provided the numerator doesn't go any faster to infinity, we're probably all right. Once we have a hypothesis for the values of $k$ for which there is a limit, we can prove it.

Comment: I worked it by dividing everything by 5^-2x and now have 5^x(k+2)  since the bottom half ended up being 1 and the top ends up 5^x(k+2) - 0, but I just dont know what to make of it from here. could K be all numbers except 2

Comment: If $k > -2$ then the limit does not exist. If $k = -2$, the limit is $1$. If $k < -2$ the limit is zero. Work on showing those.

Comment: I guess I'm still not completely grasping it

Comment: If you can't visualize or otherwise see what's going on, use a tool to graph for different values of $k$, e.g., http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+%285%5E%28-2x%29-1%29%2F%285%5E%28-2x%29+%2B+1%29%2C+x+%3D+-3..0 Remember to look at the behavior for $x$ large, negative.

Comment: wait I think I understand now.  when its set up as 5^kx/5^-2x the limit DNE when K is >-2 because the answer is always approaching zero but in all other cases its either 1 or a finite amount?

Answer (score 1):

One more hint:

$$\frac{5^{kx}-1}{5^{-2x} + 1} = \frac{5^{kx}}{5^{-2x} + 1} - \frac{1}{5^{-2x} + 1} = \frac{1}{5^{-(2+k)x} + 5^{-kx}} - \frac{1}{5^{-2x} + 1} $$